# I was trying to enter the String using next() and there is an error while comparing the strings using equals() from string class

Tags: java, string

I have entered the string **abc def** 
and the equals() has returned true while comparing the entered string with the given string **abc**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class StringManipulation
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter username");
        String a = s.next();                   // abc def
        System.out.println(a.equals("abc"));   // return true at execution time
    }
}
```

Comment: `s.next()` reads a single token (i.e. until a white space or new line is encountered). Therefore `a` contains "abc". Use `s.nextLine()` if you wish to read the entire line.

Comment: That's expected, given what Scanner.next() does. Read its documentation. It does not do the same thing as nextLine().

Comment: `next()` takes only one token. Tokens are separated by delimiters which for scanner is set as *one or more whitespace* so here next token is only `abc`. If you want to read entire line use `nextLine()`

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly and remove unnecessary whitespace for your next post.

Comment: yea sure :)  @csmckelvey